# Find a basis for the subspace of the vectors $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ satisfying $z_1+z_2+z_3=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need help with the following question:

Find a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$ of all the vectors $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ satisfying
$$z_1+z_2+z_3=0$$
Thanks!

Comment: Can you come up with any vectors in $C^3?$

Answer (score 1):

Two vectors which satisfy that equation are $(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$; also, they are linearly independent.

Let's see that these two vectors generate any solution to that equation.

If $(z_{1},z_{2},z_{3})$ is a solution of $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = 0$ then $z_{3}=-z_{1}-z_{2},$ that is  $(z_{1},z_{2},z_{3})=(z_{1},z_{2},-z_{1}-z_{2})=z_{1}(1,0,-1)+z_{2}(0,1,-1),$ so our solution is generated by the two aforementioned vectors.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  You can choose two of $z_1,z_2,z_3$ freely, and the third will be determined by the equation $z_1+z_2+z_3=0$.  Thus the space is $2$-dimensional.

So you just need two independent solutions.